# Can't access some websites using any browser

Tags: 16.04, internet, browser

I can't access some websites using any browsers. However if I clear everything(history, cache, cookies etc.) of the browser, I can access the website for some time. But after some time I can't access them anymore. However I can ping those websites any time and other users of the same ISP can access the websites too. How to access these websites without clearing the browser?

Comment: Try to access these website in browser private mode. (in Chrome Ctrl+N or Ctrl+Shift+N)

Comment: It is possible to access them in private mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by connecting using `sudo pppoeconf` command. But connection using network manager was still messy.